# Focus first element of the selected md-tab programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

How do we focus the md-tab first element (e.g. input) when we programmatically changed the md-tab `selectedIndex`?

Template

```
<md-tab-group #tg>
    <md-tab label="Tab1">
       <button md-button (click)="nextTab(tg)">Goto tab 2</button>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Tab2">
       <md-form-field>
           <input id="_input1" mdInput #input1>
       </md-form-field>

       <md-form-field>
           <input id="_input2" mdInput #input2>
       </md-form-field>
    </md-tab>
<md-tab-group>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('input1') vcInput1: any;

nextTab(tab: any): void {
   setTimeout(_=> {

       // tab changes to Tab2
       this.vcTg.selectedIndex = 1;

       // nothing happened
       this.vcInput1.nativeElement.focus();

      // null
      console.log(document.getElementById('_input1'))
   })
}
```

Despite searching any related problem. I couldn't find the right explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the focus of input in `(selectChange)` event of `MdTabGroup` and get your `input1` as `ElementRef`. Here is the code:

In you html template:

```
<md-tab-group #tg (selectChange)="tabSelectionChanged($event)">
```

and in your ts code:

```
@ViewChild('input1') vcInput1: ElementRef;

nextTab(): void {       
    // tab changes to Tab2
    this.vcTg.selectedIndex = 1;
}

tabSelectionChanged(event: MdTabChangeEvent){
    if(event.index === 1){
        this.vcInput1.nativeElement.focus(); 
    } 
}
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8oicj?file=app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

Use (selectChange) event to detect which tab is selected:

**Typescript:**

```
@ViewChild('input1') vcInput1: any;
@ViewChild('input2') vcInput2: any;

nextTab(tab: any): void {
    console.log(tab)

if(tab.index==0) {
        // nothing happened
        this.vcInput1.nativeElement.focus();
    }
if(tab.index===1) {
        // nothing happened
        this.vcInput2.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    // null
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="nextTab($event)" >
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1
  <input  #input1>

  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2
    <input #input2 >

  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Ptd9IrAQVtfHyXjfgFi?p=preview)